# Cube rotating to other face doesn't animate with three.js

Tags: vue.js, three.js

Why the code below doesn't animate my cube when rotating to another face ? How should I fix it ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null,
      rotationPerc: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init: function () {
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
      });
      let container = document.getElementById('container');
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 1000);
      this.camera.position.z = 400;

      // Make a scene
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // 1. Start with empty geometry
      let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

      // 2. Add vertices to geometry
      geometry.vertices.push(
        // verts [0-3] are in in +z
        new THREE.Vector3(-100, 100, 100),
        new THREE.Vector3(-100, -100, 100),
        new THREE.Vector3(100, -100, 100),
        new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 100),
        // verts [4-7] in -z
        new THREE.Vector3(-100, 100, -100),
        new THREE.Vector3(-100, -100, -100),
        new THREE.Vector3(100, -100, -100),
        new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, -100),
      );

      // 3. Connect vertices in desired order to make faces
      let b = 0x1db0ec
      let y = 0xffef3a
      let r = 0xea353d
      let w = 0xffffff
      //
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2)); // blue
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3)); // yellow
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 4, 6)); // white
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(6, 4, 7)); // red
      //
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 0, 5)); // blue
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 0, 4));
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 5, 2)); // white
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 6, 2));
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(2, 6, 3)); // red
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 6, 7));
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 4)); // yellow
      geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 7, 4));
      //
      geometry.faces[0].color.setHex(b);
      geometry.faces[1].color.setHex(y);
      geometry.faces[2].color.setHex(w);
      geometry.faces[3].color.setHex(r);
      //
      geometry.faces[4].color.setHex(b);
      geometry.faces[5].color.setHex(b);
      geometry.faces[6].color.setHex(w);
      geometry.faces[7].color.setHex(w);
      geometry.faces[8].color.setHex(r);
      geometry.faces[9].color.setHex(r);
      geometry.faces[10].color.setHex(y);
      geometry.faces[11].color.setHex(y);

      // Make a material
      let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        // color: 0x00FF00,
        vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
        wireframe: false,
      });

      // Create a mesh based on the geometry and material
      this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.scene.add(this.mesh);

    },
    rotateTo: function (face) {
      if (face == 'yellow')
        this.mesh.rotation.set(0, Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc, Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc);
      else if (face == 'red')
        this.mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc, 0, Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc);
      else if (face == 'blue')
        this.mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc, 0, - Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc);
      else if (face == 'white')
        this.mesh.rotation.set(- Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc, Math.PI / 2 * this.rotationPerc, 0);
      else if (face == 'yb')
        this.mesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
      else if (face == 'rw')
        this.mesh.rotation.set(Math.PI * this.rotationPerc, 0, 0);

      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

      if (this.rotationPerc < 1) {
        this.rotationPerc += 0.001
        this.rotateTo(face)
      } else {
        this.rotationPerc = 1
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.init();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 0.1em;
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div>
      <button v-on:click="rotateTo('yellow')">yellow</button>
      <button v-on:click="rotateTo('red')">red</button>
      <button v-on:click="rotateTo('blue')">blue</button>
      <button v-on:click="rotateTo('white')">white</button>
      <button v-on:click="rotateTo('yb')">yellow/blue</button>
      <button v-on:click="rotateTo('rw')">red/white</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animation objects in interactive 2D/3D applications, it's recommended to use an animation loop. You perform the changes without any delay, so the transition happens extremely fast. Besides, it's recommended to avoid euler angles when animating rotation. Use quaternions instead. `three.js` provides a method [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards) which is ideal for your use case. The first parameter defines the target rotation, the second parameter defines the angular step in radians. Meaning it will gradually rotate your object towards the defined target rotation. This is similar to how Unity's [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) works. The `three.js` implementation will also ensure that the object does not "overshoot".

Put in your animation loop the following two lines:

```js
var delta = clock.getDelta(); // clock is an instance of THREE.Clock

mesh.quaternion.rotateTowards( targetRotation, step * delta );
```

`step` defines the angular displacement in seconds. Check out the following fiddle for a complete example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hx06vn8p/1/

`three.js R111`

Comment: Great answer, thanks! However, the `animate()` method in your jsfiddle is an infinite loop, although the cube has finished to rotate. How to stop it once the cube has finished its rotation ?

Comment: You can stop the animation loop by canceling the animation frame request via [window.cancelAnimationFrame()](window.cancelAnimationFrame()).

Comment: How to know when the rotation has finished ? I could use a timer, but I hope there's a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: In this case, you can check if the current quaternion values are equal to the target ones. Something like `if ( mesh.quaternion.equals( targetQuaternion ) ) {}`.

Comment: Thanks, that works well but not perfectly. I have updated my code above to show the problem. Sometimes, it's not animated or very quickly. Do you know how it should be fixed ?

Comment: I have open a new question for this last issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525515/why-cubes-do-not-always-animate-with-three-js